# How to update table using schema compare while data is in table?

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2015, schema, database-schema

*Using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015*

I would like to use schema compare to update a bunch of table changes from a test environment to my local one.

**I'm getting the error:**

> Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss
>   might occur.

So this is saying I have data in the tables I want to update and I could lose data if I made the table changes. But I'm going to do a data compare afterward the get the updated data as well. How can I override the above error and force the changes? Or do I have to just truncate the tables with data in them first?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in the settings.

Click on the options Cog wheel that's next to the compare and update buttons.

Next click on the General tab and then uncheck "Block on possible data loss"

[image]

Hope this helps someone in the future.